# How can I run glances over ssh?

Tags: ssh, terminal, remote

I installed *glances* on my remote server, and now I'm trying to connect to it from my local machine and run it, like this :

```
ssh user@host glances
```

which gives me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/glances", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('Glances==1.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'glances')()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/glances.py", line 4644, in main
use_bold=use_bold)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/glances.py", line 1937, in __init__
self.screen = curses.initscr()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())

_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've given a single command for `ssh` to run remotely, ssh did not allocate a pseudo-terminal for glances to use. Simply add the `-t` option to ssh to force it:

```
ssh -t user@host glances
```

Reference:

[ssh man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh)

> When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server either executes the given command in a non-interactive session

...

> If an interactive session is requested ssh by default will only request a pseudo-terminal (pty) for interactive sessions when the client has one. The flags -T and -t can be used to override this behaviour.